# list of figures reference to image, caption on another page

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions

Using the caption package to put a caption of a figure on another page, the List of Figures shows the number of the page where the caption is, not the page where the actual image is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\rule{10cm}{2cm}
\caption*{}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\captionof{figure}{Figure on another page.}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to correctly reference the figure page at the List of Figures, instead of the caption page?

Comment: I can't see the point in having an 'orphan' caption hanging around but no image, but perhaps you can explain?

Comment: It's not an orphan caption; it's just a caption on a page referring to an image on another page. It's very common in art books.

Comment: Perhaps I should read more art books then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution might be heavily dependent on your setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \rule{10cm}{2cm}
  \refstepcounter{figure}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}Fig caption}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\begingroup
\renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Avoid writing to LoF
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
\captionof{figure}{Figure on another page.}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks OK, but quite a lot of work for every figure I might need to put a caption on a separate page. Also, where does `\thefigure` get its counter from? I mean, does it add to the counter of the previous figures?

Comment: @Joseph: I just showed you that it's doable... you didn't mention this would be "a lot of work"... Of course one could wrap the entire thing into an environment called (say) `fignextpagecaption`. Do you have many of these types of figures?